# Possibility to automate installation of desktop application in Vagrant

Tags: powershell, automation, vagrant

What I have: Vagrant, desktop application which I need to install (Windows application (exe)), folder which is shared in corporate network (where application builds are held).

What I need to do:

1. Install Vagrant (for now I do it manually) - completed;
2. Install Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 boxes (for now I do it manually) - completed;
3. Get the newest build of application (.exe file) from folder which is shared in corporate network (there are several files in that folder), put it in Vagrant machine (Win 8 for example) and silently install on in.

All process should be automated as much as possible.

But I can't combine Vagrant and copy/install application to Vagrant machine. I dig in PowerShell - but no luck... I have PowerShell script for silent installation, but maybe there is ability to create one script for all these action (in PowerShell for example)? I know that I can use Chocolatey but I need a script which could do step by step actions.

Comment: Is it a possibility to deploy image of a Windows, using let's say FileZilla, Hyper-V, VMWare or similar?

Comment: Sure, why not. I am building everything from the scratch so why not try all possible solutions? Except VMWare. I chose Vagrant + PowerShell because it's easy to create Windows virtual machine and PowerShell because I have script which is written in PS (with silent installation options). Basically, I need to test installation process in Windows (8.1  and 10) environment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating very simple script which is based in Chocolatey commands (script installs Vagrant, VirtualBox, copy files which I need, create folders which I need):

```
# Set PowerShell policy to Unrestricted

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

# Install Chocolatey
iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex

# Turn off confirmation in Chocolatey
chocolatey feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation

# Install Vagrant
choco install vagrant

# Install VirutalBox
choco install virtualbox

# Create folder where Vagrant box will be placed
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "D:\VagrantBoxes\Win8"

# Create folder where release will be placed
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "D:\Release"

# Map network drive (release folder)
New-PSDrive –Name “B” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root 
“\\r\P\A\OS\D B\R 2\x64” –Persist

# Map network drive (vagrant boxes folder)

New-PSDrive –Name “B” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root 
“\\r\P\A\A\V M\V m” –Persist

# Copy Vagrant box from network folder
Copy-Item -Path 
"B:\windows_81x64-enterprise_virtualbox_15.07.17.box" -Destination "D:\VagrantBoxes\Win8"

# Copy newest build from network folder to remote machine

Get-ChildItem "B:\" -Filter '*.exe' | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1 | Copy-Item -Destination 'D:\'

# Navigate to folder where Vagrant file will be placed

CD "D:\VagrantBoxes\Win8"

# Mount Windows box

vagrant init windows_81x64-enterprise_virtualbox_15.07.17.box

# Run Vagrant

vagrant up
```

Second script is for installation process of a software inside Windows machine (I can't post this code here).